# SharePoint list views - different permissions for different views

Tags: list, permissions, list-view

I have a SharePoint list that is currently setup so that users can only see the items they create. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to create a view or duplicate the list or something for one group to have admin access to and view/edit all items.

So say User 1 submits a new item, User 2 submits 2 items and User 3 submits 1 item. These users can only see the items they submitted.
The Admin Group is able to see all 4 items submitted.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try item level permissions?

Comment: If you give the Admin Group design level access it'll override the "can only see the items they create" permission and will allow them to see all items.  I believe that accomplishes what you're asking?

Comment: I did try both options, neither worked. As an admin with full control over the site I'm not able to see items I don't create.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  You need to do the following:

1. **Set the item level permissions** for the list under List Settings --> Advanced Settings
   [image]
2. **Break the permission inheritance** for this list.  List Setting -- Permissions for list and modify the permission for the visitor group (or the desired group) to 'Contribute'
3. **Create a group for the admin** and give this group full access to this list.

Answer (score 1):

**Single User View:** What you are wanting to accomplish can be done within the *`List Setting > Advanced Settings > Item Level Permission.`* Here you can set it up so that users can only view/edit items they created.

**Editor/Admin View:**
The easiest way for you to have someone who can edit and view all the user's items is to create a group of "admins" or "editors" and give them permission to view/edit the list data.

**Duplicating List/Views:** You asked if there was a way of creating a duplicate view or list, and the short answer is yes. You can duplicate the list web part in edit mode and set the target audiences settings of the two parts. This will let you target which group you would like to see specific views; however, I would not recommend this method as there are easier ways by just setting permission levels