# Create a View to Show Current User's Assigned Items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, list, view

I'm looking for ideas on how to display a user's assigned items. This is more than just creating a view and filtering the list based on the current user. I need some way to show the user what items are still pending review and then they can delete the item once it is complete. The issue with them deleting the item is that it would delete its instance altogether.

So here is my thought process:

-Place a Create a list item after each new item is assigned to a user
    -Filter the new list to show only items assigned to the current user

At first, I think that this option would work, but then I think of how although it has the same fields and information of the main list, it is disassociated with it. I wouldn't want the Users to try to go in and edit the item like they would with the main list because it wouldn't capture the information in the correct place.

We have tried the assign a task process, and that didn't work.
I'm just trying to search for any other options I may be missing or not aware of.

Comment: As per your requirement, the Workflow tasks would fit perfect but you mentioned it didn`t work. May I know it is not solving your business scenario or you are having any issues?

Comment: I thought I did everything by the book when I set it up. I created the site content type with a parent of "SharePoint Workflow 2013". I added my new site columns and removed a lot of the columns that were currently there that I didn't need. I even created custom outcome choices and assigned them within the Assign a Task action. What it came down to is that 1)The item itself is what I need approved, not the task. 2) Despite if they selected the outcome choice (Approved, Rejected), the task wouldn't complete.

Comment: I agree task won`t set status completed on approve. But workflow can set the task status as completed and % completed to 1. And workflow can set your item status to approved.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the requirement fully but I think you can achieve this through list item level permissions.  Have a look at this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/217259/49449

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SharePoint 2013 on-prem (as you tag your question), event receivers can solve your problem. Try following concept:

Create a new yes/no (Boolean type) column into your list, lets name it `isDeleted`. Create your view with all the conditions you want and add one more condition if column `isDeleted is equals No`. Now the desired items area displayed to your user. Add an synchronous item deleting event receiver to your list. Put the condition, if `review is equals completed` set `isDeleted` flag to `true` and finally prevent your item deletion by using `properties.Cancel = true;` in event receiver code and update item.

Using the above concept, the actual item never gets deleted, but the flag `isDeleted` is updated and the item wont be visible in the view to user anymore.

Comment: I saw you update tags to SharePoint-Online, so this option wont be applicable for you.

Comment: Even for SPO you can use the same concept, only constrain is you cant use the OOTB delete feature of list item. Instead create a new delete button and use the same concept i.e. setting the isDeleted flag.