# SharePoint Form with Hidden List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view

I want to set up a form on my home SharePoint page for people to enter themselves into a drawing/raffle. What I was thinking would work best would be to have a front end form that all users can see and submit their name through, but have a hidden list that only a isolated audience could view. What would be the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list with item level permission so even if user reached the list through a url, they will only see their own item.  You can give users a 'Contribute' access so they can add/update the item. You can create a group for authorised staff with full control on the list so they can see everything.

More information on how to achieve item level permission on the list is [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217255/sharepoint-list-views-different-permissions-for-different-views/217259#217259)